# window.open() is not working after hosted in server

Tags: window

It through the error in console : **Unable to open a window with invalid URL '%3144.76.2.51:3001/api/web/bizsteps/export/?content={%22bizSteps%22:[{%22bizStep%22:%22Make%22,%22bizLocation%22:[{%22name%22:%22Field%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22},{%22name%22:%22Pre-Cool%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22}]},{%22bizStep%22:%22Store%22,%22bizLocation%22:[{%22name%22:%22Location%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22}]},{%22bizStep%22:%22Transport%22,%22bizLocation%22:[{%22name%22:%22Journey%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22},{%22name%22:%22East%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22}]},{%22bizStep%22:%22Sell%22,%22bizLocation%22:[{%22name%22:%22DC%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22},{%22name%22:%22Retail%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22}]},{%22bizStep%22:%22Use%22,%22bizLocation%22:[{%22name%22:%22Best%22,%22time%22:%22%22,%22temperature%22:%22%22,%22freshTimePoint%22:%22%22}]}],%22product%22:%22%22,%22brand%22:%22%22,%22demographic%22:%22%22,%22region%22:%22%22,%22type%22:%22%22,%22fileName%22:%22%22}&type=PDF'**

The above is my URL which i try to open in new window.

what is the problem in it and its working for some other urls .
help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying the `http://` protocol in the url.

You need to change this:

```
%3144.76.2.51:3001/api/web/...
```

to this

```
http%3A%2F%2F144.76.2.51:3001/api/web/...
```